# How can i move the button to the center (html,jsp)?

Tags: html, button

please tell me what to do to move my button to the center of the page. beacause right now it is in the right corner and i tried a lot of times to move it.

```
        <style>
        .button {
            background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
            border: none;
            color: white;
            padding: 13px 32px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 17px;
            cursor: pointer;
            -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
            transition-duration: 0.4s;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .button1:hover {
            box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
        }
    </style>


    <button class="button button1" type="button" onclick="history.back()" value="חזור וחשב מחדש">חשב מחדש</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Horizontal aligment, you need to put css on the containing div, to control the child element...

```
.container {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

<div class="container">
    <button class="button button1" type="button" onclick="history.back()" value="חזור וחשב מחדש">חשב מחדש</button>
</div>
```

If you are looking to vertically center the element, use...

```
button {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can do it with flexbox, it's a powerful way to quickly center elements both horizontally and vertically.

You just have to put your button inside a container, apply flexbox to it, then `margin: auto;` will do the rest.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
 
.button {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="button button1" type="button" onclick="history.back()" value="חזור וחשב מחדש">חשב מחדש</button>
</div>
```